# Silly mod_rewrite issue

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I think I never asked before a question like this, and I know I should read the manual, so I did, but I simply can't make this work.

I need a rewrite rule to move from this:

```
https://www.proevisa.com/ar/idea.php?permalink=proevisa/is-it-safe-to-provide-my-personal-and-finance-information-online
```

to this:

```
https://www.proevisa.com/ar/proevisa/is-it-safe-to-provide-my-personal-and-finance-information-online
```

I don't yet understand if I should update the links on the website, as they point to the original URL not the pretty ones.

Can someone please help me out a little bit with this?

Thanks a lot,
Chris

Comment: You should show your current attempted code to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there was no query string involved, `RedirectMatch` could be used (not sure why it was made to ignore that part of URLs, or maybe I am mistaken).

Anyway, with mod_rewrite try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING} ^/ar/idea\.php\?permalink=(.*?)$
RewriteRule . /ar/%1? [R=301]
```

This is assuming there is a `RewriteEngine On` directive present, and there are no other mod_rewrite rules that could mix in (if there are, consider using the `L` flag or rearranging the rules).

`%1` references the contents of the regexp "group" after the `permalink=`. `?` after it tells to omit the old query string from the result. `R=301` is a permanent redirect.

Of course, update the links on the site, and after old links are gone from indexes and bookmarks, remove the rules as they will become irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks *1000 Times Gas Welder... htaccess is really not for me.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally came to more PHP based solution as my mod_rewrite skill aren't really good. This is what I've done:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /proevisa/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /proevisa/ar/idea.php?r=$1
</IfModule>
```

Yes, it's based on the Wordpress rewrite structure. What it does it's basically the following:

1. Defines the base path as Proevisa which is my home directory.
2. If the requested URL is not a file
3. If the requested URL is not a directory
4. Then, it's redirected to idea.php

Idea.php does the following:

```
//recibimos la información del usuario
$idea->base_dir = "/proevisa/ar";
$idea->permalink = addslashes($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$idea->permalink = str_replace($idea->base_dir, "", $idea->permalink);
```

1. Defines once again the base directory.
2. Analyzes the original request URI
3. Cleans it a little bit to avoid issues with the permalinks.

Then we query the database to see if there's any article matching the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].

It's not an specific solution for the problem I've described, but it works very well to handle almost every single case using PHP, as if it's not found you can easily redirect to a PHP, or even you can use LIKE in the query, and show similar results...

Hope it helps someone!
Chris;